# How to catch a duplicate like `-Wduplicated-cond` from GCC-6

Tags: c, gcc, gcc6

Like the title says, for those who already know starting with `GCC-6` you can catch a duplicate in an `if`statement using this Flag `-Wduplicated-cond` like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
    int a = 5;

    if( a == 5){
        printf("First  condition is True, A = %d\n", a);
    }else if( a == 5 ){
        printf("Second condition is True, A = %d\n", a);
    }
}
```

And the Output will be:

```
program.c:8:17: warning: duplicated ‘if’ condition [-Wduplicated-cond]
     }else if( a == 5 ){
               ~~^~~~
program.c:6:11: note: previously used here
     if( a == 5){
         ~~^~~~
```

Now I know that the following:

`else if( (a > 4) && (a < 6) )`

is not the same like

`else if( a == 5 )`

but there happens that I do a check for the same condition if `a == 5`.

My Question is, is there any chances to can catch (to avoid) this kind of duplicate?

Comment: I doubt it will get catched...the analysis is too complex for such a minor thing.

Comment: I think that `if( a == 5)` and `else if( a == 5 )` produces the same instructions and  `else if( (a > 4) && (a < 6) )` produces different instruction[s] which probably means that the compiler checks if the same instructions are taking place and not if the conditions are taking(produces) the same result. I'm not sure if I'm right.

Comment: Michi,open your eyes well while you are coding.

Comment: In this specific case `(a > 4) && (a < 6)` is the same as `(a == 5)` but that'
s only true for `int` (and variations).

Comment: @machine_1 I do this all the time, but even so I find `-Wduplicated-cond` a good thing

Comment: @fpg1503 You mean that produces the same result, or you mean that the Compiler will use the same Instructions?

Comment: @Michi I mean produces the same result, the generated instructions on GCC are completely different. The compiler is able to get that case: if you take a look at the generated assembly code using any optimization higher than `-O2` the second if branch is completely removed.

Comment: @fpg1503 Yes, is true, but even with `-O3` the warning will still be there.

Comment: @Michi IMHO under `-O2` or `O3` there should be `-Wunreachable-code` or `-Wduplicated-cond` (probably both) in this case. I thinks it's a GCC bug.

Comment: @fpg1503 It's not a bug but intended feature. See my answer.

Answer (score -1):

`-Wduplicated-cond` does catch this case. You have to explicitly enable it.

> main.cpp: In function 'int main()':
>
> main.cpp:8:11: warning: duplicated 'if' condition [-Wduplicated-cond]
>
> ```
>  }else if( a == 5 ){
>        ^~
> ```
>
> main.cpp:6:5: note: previously used here
>
> ```
>  if( a == 5){
> ```

It was originally [enabled by `-Wall`](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-patches/2015-09/msg01200.html) but not anymore because of [PR67819](https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc-patches/2015-10/msg00245.html):

> Given that the new warning currently breaks bootstrap [*] and I see no
>   simple way how to resolve PR67819 derived out of the bootstrap
>   failure, I'm moving -Wduplicated-cond out of -Wall and skipping one of
>   the tests for the time being.  I'm also reverting the hack in
>   genemit.c.

Comment: The OP is talking about duplicate detection when using different statements that are logically equivalent (i.e. `a == 5` and `a > 4 && a < 6`).